# How to assert inside bash function regardless of logic check?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'd like to implement a global trap for my bash script that I fires when anything fails. Trouble is that if I have an if clause that is evaluating a function that is a predicate and while evaluating that predicate there is a failure, then the trap is not called. I understand that traps are not invoked if a predicate returns false but I didn't expect that the logic computing the predicate to also have the trap disabled. Is my interpretation of the behavior correct and is there anyway to have bash invoke a trap on logic computing a predicate?

For example,

```
$ trap 'echo $?' ERR
$ set -eE
$ foo() { return 1; }
$ bar() { foo; return 0; }
$ bar
1
```

So far, so good. I define a trap, ask that any failure trigger the trap, and ask that all functions inherit the trap. Then I call `bar` which calls `foo` which fails, invokes the trap, and prints the error code `1`.

```
$ if bar; then echo true; fi
true
```

This is unexpected. I expected the output to be `1`. I expected only the return code from `bar` to be excluded from consideration. What actually happens, I think, is that all the logic inside of `bar` is *also* excluded from consideration. Is that just the way bash works? Is there a way to specify that any logic in `bar` that fails (e.g. the call to `foo`) before the last statement (e.g. the `return 0;`) should trigger the trap?

Comment: The whole point of something like `if` or `while` is that the commands they invoke are expected to `fail` sometimes. The commands can be something simple like an echo or something complicated like invoking make to compile and deploy something. The command may even be a list of commands.

Comment: Sure. In my case, during the computation of the predicate the call to `foo` _does_ fail. And because it fails I expect the predicate to return false because `-e` is specified. But that doesn't happen. The predicate still returns `true`. It returns `true` because `-e` has been disabled for all logic contained in `bar` because `bar` is used as an `if` test. Seems odd, no? Further, I specified a trap and `-E` I so expected the trap to execute when the call to `foo` fails and before `bar` returns the error code. But that doesn't happen either because the trap is also disabled. :(

Comment: You'll want to spend some time reading about `set -e` [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin). Also [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: Thanks! Hm, just seems unfortunate that the entire call graph involved in evaluating an expression in an `if` statement ignores `-e`. But that is apparently exactly what it does and that behavior is explicitly documented. I wonder why they didn't choose to ignore only the final result of the call graph returned to the `if` statement and honor `-e` for any other commands that fail during the evaluation of the expression. Not that it really matters, I guess.